# pexpect trying to print the contents of a remote file

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm learning pexpect and trying to automate the listing of a log file on a remote servers, so far I can get the printout only if i add child.interact() at the end.

What I'd like to do is ssh to the server, cat the log file and print the output to the screen so I can log it on the local server.

```
import pexpect


child = pexpect.spawn('ssh admin@172.16.200.51')
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline('some pass')
child.expect('>')
child.sendline('enable')
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('su')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('somepass')
child.expect('$')
child.sendline('cat /var/log/vent2.log')
child.expect(''$')
print(child.before)
```

im not sure why its not printing out.

Comment: Is this line okay? `child.expect(''$')`

Comment: yes, its a typo but i updated it and I get the same result.   The script is definitely running the command because f I add                                `child.interact()`   after the command print, it works but leaves me at  prompt at the remote server.   So the question is how do I capture the output of the file and print it to screen so I can log it or how do I take the output of the cat command and log it locally.

Comment: The file probably contains `$` somewhere in it, so the `expect()` is only reading up to that. Try using [pxssh](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/pxssh.html) or [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_simple.py) to drive an SSH session.

Comment: I tried pxssh but I can't even get it to log into the server. It gives me error stating it can figure out what the starting prompt it.

Comment: Did you try `child.expect(pexpect.EOF)` to wait for all output of a child to finish?

Comment: CCF - thanks, yes I did, it just hangs

Comment: So it was fixed by escaping the $ , child.expect(''\$")

Comment: @DRO right, should have spotted that. `expect()` takes a regex pattern by default, so $ means the end of the string, and the way Pexpect checks it, it could match anywhere. You can also use `expect_exact()` to match a regular string.

Comment: @ThomasK - thanks for the tip. I will try  using expect_exact( )